# how to use anko library in androidx

Tags: android, api, android-studio, anko

so I want to use **Anko** library on my apps by use Androidx, and I want to add Anko library inside of my apps on android studio, I use API version 30, android 10.0+ (R), but when I Add Anko library on my project I get the error :

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.8] /Users/anjay/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1d0aabee6b3e238a89acc21f650d01a8/jetified-anko-design-0.10.8/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.jetbrains.anko.generated.design" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

This is my build.gradle (Module level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apithemoviedb"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // implementasi atau library androidx design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'

    // implementasi atau library androidx anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"


    // RecyclerView-v7
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"


    //implementasi atau library picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //implementasi atau library Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

This is my build.gradle (project level):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apithemoviedb">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand... How about just increase minSdkVersion as the error log said and see what's gonna happen?